# Understanding the difference between this.function() and this.function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hi I have been reading on react as well as doing some coding and I can't help but notice that in certain portions of the code we will use `this.function()` and in some we will call using `this.function`, I do not understand what is the difference between them and how do i determine when should i call with `()` and when should i not.

For example I can have the following code which will use `this.function`

```
//Arrow function used to bind the necessary variables
CallFunction = (event) =>{ 
   console.log("Event was called");
}

render(){
   return(
      <form onSubmit={this.CallFunction} />
   );
}
```

Next I can have the following code

```
CallFunction () {
   console.log("Event was called");
}

render(){
   return(
      <div>{this.CallFunction()}</div>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just plain ole javascript, it's the difference between executing a function and just *referencing* a function. If you have the parens, that function will get executed immediately upon render. So in your second example you would see 'Event was called' immediately in your console when this component mounts. There are several reasons why we might have to do this, a simple one is that we just want to break out some of our code to a new function to make things easier to read.

With callbacks we don't want to execute the function right away, so we don't use the parens. We are just *referencing* the function. We're basically saying here's the function I want you to execute when someone submits this form. If we used the parens, that function would execute immediately on the component mounting - not wait until the form is submitted.

edit: Sometimes you need to have a function execute on render and then return a *new* function you want to execute as an event handler callback:

```
function thisRunsOnRender () {
  return function thisRunsOnSubmit (e) {
    console.log(e) // this would be the submit event
  }
}

....

render () (
  <form onSubmit={thisRunsOnRender()} />
)
```

Comment: I see, just to double confirm based on your answer am I right to assume that `this.function` will only run upon a `onSubmit` event, that is to say when `render()` is called it will not be triggered. On the other hand, `this.function()` will only trigger when `render()` is called.

Hence, if I ever place `this.function()` into `<form onSubmit={this.function()}/>` it will cause an error as `this.function()` is being called when `render()` is triggered.

Comment: Yep - more or less. Executing a function in that event handler might not actually cause an 'error' as in a runtime error, but it could cause a bug if you didn't mean to execute that function immediately on render.

Comment: Just one more thing i forgot to add. If I use `<form onSubmit={this.function()}/>` will it also activate the function if i do a `onSubmit` event?

Comment: No. Although sometimes you might need to do something like have a function there that returns a *new* function. In that case the new function would execute

Comment: If i do that I assume that the `new function` returned by `<form onSubmit={this.function()}/>` will only execute upon `render()` correct?

Comment: Nope if you return an actual function, that one will only execute on submit. I'll update my answer to provide an example.